# Can ping but can't access certain site

Tags: networking, browser, ping

I'm having problem with accessing certain website and I do not have any clue where to check.

I'm trying to access www.jobsdb.com, and this is the error message -

```
This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.
The incident ID is: N/A.
```

I can access google.com or another website just fine.
Another thing is, I'm trying to ping www.jobsdb.com and I can ping it.

After ping, I'm trying to access www.jobsdb.com with IP Address in the browser, but it still show the error message.

I have tried using Google Chrome and firefox for the browser, and it still the same.
What can I do to 'unblock' it?

Comment: I don't know much about networking either, but I'd start by opening Notepad as an Administrator, add `202.45.131.130  www.jobsdb.com` to the bottom of your hosts file (`202.45.131.130` is what I get when I ping the site) `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`, close Firefox entirely (this will prevent cached hostfile records from being used), re-open Firefox, and try to access `www.jobsdb.com` again. If it works perhaps you have a DNS issue, if it doesn't then perhaps it's an issue with your computer (eg: a Firewall rule). REVERT the changes to your hosts file when done.

Comment: Go into safe mode with networking and try and access the site from there.  That will narrow down a lot of things in windows potentially blocking you.